# ViewPager and updating TextView; Fatal exception?

Tags: android, exception, android-viewpager

I am trying to get ViewPager to work, but one section of my code is causing an issue. The section of the code that is problematic is posted directly below. From what I suspect, my TextViews are repeatedly being updated as the position is being iterated to the value set in method getCount(), which is the size of my array.

Anyway, below all of this is my code in full as I have it so far.

Problematic code from ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
            // Capture position and set to the TextViews
            tvNumber.setText(arrayAtomicNum.get(position));
            tvSymbol.setText(arraySymbol.get(position));
            tvName.setText(arrayName.get(position));
            tvGroup.setText(arrayGroup.get(position));
            tvPeriod.setText(arrayPeriod.get(position));
            tvBlock.setText(arrayBlock.get(position));
            tvFamily.setText(arrayFamily.get(position));
            tvColor.setText(arrayColor.get(position));
            tvPhase.setText(arrayPhase.get(position));
            tvNeutrons.setText(arrayNeutrons.get(position));
            tvProtons.setText(arrayProtons.get(position));
            tvElectrons.setText(arrayElectrons.get(position));
```

Here is the whole class, ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public static String TAG = ViewPagerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    List<Integer> arrayAtomicNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> arrayName = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arraySymbol = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arrayFamily = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arrayPhase = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arrayColor = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> arrayGroup = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> arrayPeriod = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> arrayBlock = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> arrayProtons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> arrayNeutrons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> arrayElectrons = new ArrayList<Integer>();    


    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> arrayAtomicNum, 
            List<String> arrayName, List<String> arraySymbol, List<String> arrayFamily,
            List<String> arrayPhase, List<String> arrayColor, List<Integer> arrayGroup, 
            List<Integer> arrayPeriod, List<String> arrayBlock, List<Integer> arrayProtons,
            List<Integer> arrayNeutrons, List<Integer> arrayElectrons) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayAtomicNum = arrayAtomicNum;
        this.arrayName = arrayName;
        this.arraySymbol = arraySymbol;
        this.arrayFamily = arrayFamily;
        this.arrayPhase = arrayPhase;
        this.arrayColor = arrayColor;
        this.arrayGroup = arrayGroup;
        this.arrayPeriod = arrayPeriod;
        this.arrayBlock = arrayBlock;
        this.arrayProtons = arrayProtons;
        this.arrayNeutrons = arrayNeutrons;
        this.arrayElectrons = arrayElectrons;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return 0;
        return arrayAtomicNum.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return false;
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);

    }

     @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            // Declare Variables
            TextView tvNumber; // container for atomic number
            TextView tvSymbol; // container for symbol
            TextView tvName; // container for name
            TextView tvGroup; // container for group
            TextView tvPeriod; // container for period
            TextView tvBlock; // container for block
            TextView tvFamily; // container for family
            TextView tvColor; // container for color
            TextView tvPhase; // container for phase
            TextView tvNeutrons; // container for neutrons
            TextView tvProtons; // container for protons
            TextView tvElectrons; // container for electrons

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_learn, container,
                    false);

            // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml
            // atomic number textView
            tvNumber = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metanumber);

            // symbol textView
            tvSymbol = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metasymbol);

            // name textView
            tvName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metaname);

            // group textView
            tvGroup = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metagroup);

            // period textView
            tvPeriod = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metaperiod);

            // block textView
            tvBlock = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metablock);

            // family textView
            tvFamily = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metafamily);

            // color textView
            tvColor = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metacolor);

            // phase textView
            tvPhase = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metaphase);

            // neutrons textView
            tvNeutrons = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metaneutrons);

            // protons textView
            tvProtons = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metaprotons);

            // electrons textView
            tvElectrons = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.metaelectrons);

            //comment out the setText and logs will print out full arrayLists
            Log.d(TAG, "arrayAtomicNum.get(position): "  + arrayAtomicNum.get(position));
            Log.d(TAG, "arraySymbol.get(position): "  + arraySymbol.get(position));
            Log.d(TAG, "arrayName.get(position): "  + arrayName.get(position));

            // Capture position and set to the TextViews
            tvNumber.setText(arrayAtomicNum.get(position));
            tvSymbol.setText(arraySymbol.get(position));
            tvName.setText(arrayName.get(position));
            tvGroup.setText(arrayGroup.get(position));
            tvPeriod.setText(arrayPeriod.get(position));
            tvBlock.setText(arrayBlock.get(position));
            tvFamily.setText(arrayFamily.get(position));
            tvColor.setText(arrayColor.get(position));
            tvPhase.setText(arrayPhase.get(position));
            tvNeutrons.setText(arrayNeutrons.get(position));
            tvProtons.setText(arrayProtons.get(position));
            tvElectrons.setText(arrayElectrons.get(position));

            // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }
}
```

I populate my arrayLists in another Activity called LearnActivity.java

```
public class LearnActivity extends Activity {
    public static String TAG = LearnActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;

    private int atomicNum = 0;

    private int temp1;
    private int temp2;

    List<Integer> arrayAtomicNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> arrayName = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arraySymbol = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arrayFamily = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arrayPhase = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> arrayColor = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> arrayGroup = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> arrayPeriod = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> arrayBlock = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> arrayProtons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> arrayNeutrons = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> arrayElectrons = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_learn);
        Log.d(TAG, "Learn layout loaded successfully");

        while (atomicNum < 3) {
        atomicNum++;

        if (atomicNum == 1) {
            ElementStructure.setName("Hydrogen");
            ElementStructure.setSymbol("H");
            ElementStructure.setFamily("Non metals");
            ElementStructure.setPhase("Gas");
            ElementStructure.setColor("Colorless");
            ElementStructure.setAtomicNum(atomicNum);
            ElementStructure.setGroup(1);
            ElementStructure.setPeriod(1);
            ElementStructure.setBlock("s");
            ElementStructure.setProton(atomicNum);
        } else if (atomicNum == 2) {
            ElementStructure.setName("Helium");
            ElementStructure.setSymbol("He");
            ElementStructure.setFamily("Noble gases");
            ElementStructure.setPhase("Gas");
            ElementStructure.setColor("Colorless");
            ElementStructure.setAtomicNum(atomicNum);
            ElementStructure.setGroup(18);
            ElementStructure.setPeriod(1);
            ElementStructure.setBlock("s");
            ElementStructure.setProton(atomicNum);
        } else if (atomicNum == 3) {
            ElementStructure.setName("Lithium");
            ElementStructure.setSymbol("Li");
            ElementStructure.setFamily("Alkali metals");
            ElementStructure.setPhase("Solid");
            ElementStructure.setColor("Silvery white");
            ElementStructure.setAtomicNum(atomicNum);
            ElementStructure.setGroup(1);
            ElementStructure.setPeriod(2);
            ElementStructure.setBlock("s");
        }

        // Atoms must have equal number(s) of protons and electrons 
        ElementStructure.setElectron(ElementStructure.getProton());

        /* Legend:
         * temp1-atomic weight rounded to nearest whole integer
         * temp2-number of neutrons */
        //temp1 = (int)Math.round(ElementStructure.getWeight());
        temp1 = 100; //just a test value
        temp2 = temp1 - ElementStructure.getProton();
        ElementStructure.setNeutron(temp2);

        // Populate arrays
        arrayAtomicNum.add(ElementStructure.getAtomicNum());
        arrayName.add(ElementStructure.getName());
        arraySymbol.add(ElementStructure.getSymbol());
        arrayFamily.add(ElementStructure.getFamily());
        arrayPhase.add(ElementStructure.getPhase());
        arrayColor.add(ElementStructure.getColor());
        arrayGroup.add(ElementStructure.getGroup());
        arrayPeriod.add(ElementStructure.getPeriod());
        arrayBlock.add(ElementStructure.getBlock());
        arrayProtons.add(ElementStructure.getProton());
        arrayNeutrons.add(ElementStructure.getNeutron());
        arrayElectrons.add(ElementStructure.getElectron());

        } //end while loop


        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(LearnActivity.this, arrayAtomicNum, arrayName,
                arraySymbol, arrayFamily, arrayPhase, arrayColor, arrayGroup, arrayPeriod,
                arrayBlock, arrayProtons, arrayNeutrons, arrayElectrons);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

}
```

All of the arrayLists have the correct values, it seems I have associated all the data I want to properly. There is more, but I am trying to keep this post limited. In either case,
what do you suppose is causing the below error? I know it is happening when attempting to setText, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to set an integer as text to TextView you should use

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));
```

if you will set just the int value TextView will try to acces the resource with that int value.

Comment: Yep! You the man Eddy, that is the reason why I was getting this error. Everything works perfect now! I will definately keep this tip in mind, now I know.